# why this code is giving Reference error: db is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have already installed mongo. it is also working at this port. also contains a database test and collection student.

```
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, datbase) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var myStudent = { name: "Jai Sharma", address: "E-3, Arera Colony, Bhopal" };

         db.collection("student").insertOne(myStudent, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 Recorded Inserted");
            db.close();
        });

    });
```

Comment: post your error as well, please

Comment: @N8888 the error seems to be in the title: "Reference error: db is not defined".

Comment: @SeanReilly that is not where the error should be placed.  It should be in the body of the question.

Comment: writing 'this' in the title is not a good way to ask a question :  [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the relevant line:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, datbase)
```

This says that the database reference should be passed in as a parameter named "datbase". Try changing that from "datbase" to "db", so that the parameter name matches the name used later in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mongodb` package version > 3.x callback no longer gives you `db` reference. Instead it gives you `client` reference as documented [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#connect-to-mongodb)

So your code should instead be:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  // note this line here. This is how you get db reference from client ref
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  ...
```